# How to detect touchesBegan, touchesMoved, touchesEnded events from another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, touchesbegan, touchesmoved, touch-event

I need to use touch events but i am trying to detect it from another class, so i will call back to my main class if touched or moved etc.
I am calling init method in "classTouchEvents" firstly from my main class like that

```
objectTouchEvents=[[classTouchEvents alloc]initWith:self.view];
```

here is initWith method of "classTouchEvents"

```
 - (id)initWith:(UIView *)selfView
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"here");
        view=[[UIView alloc]init];
        view=selfView;
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

and i get "here" log so i guess it is working but i cant detect if view get touch or anything. Here is my touch events in classTouchEvents

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    NSLog(@"touchBegan");
}
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
 NSLog(@"touchMoved");
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"touchEnded");
}
```

But i cant get any log about touches. I need some help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: UIGestureRecognizer might help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would implement a custom subclass of UIView with a delegate.

```
@protocol TouchEventsDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event inView:(UIView *)view;
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event inView:(UIView *)view;
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event inView:(UIView *)view;

@end

@property (weak, nonatomic) id<TouchEventsDelegate> delegate;
```

Implement these delegate methods in your ClassTouchEvents.

Implement the touch events method in your custom view and call the delegate.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(touchesBegan:withEventinView)]) {
        [self.delegate touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event inView:self];
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Adding `inView:(UIView *)` to the delegate methods is *bang-on*.

Comment: @lord Zsolt yes thank you, I can do it with delegates but i was thinking if there is any easier way. I am actually trying to do slide swipe menu. But i figure this out with button action, not with touch moves. But i ll accept your answer as true because it is.

Answer (score 8):

I'd use delegation:

TouchDelegate.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol TouchDelegate <NSObject>
@optional

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;

@end
```

And then in your view (that actually receives the touch event), create a `touchDelegate` property (or just `delegate` if there is unlikely to be others):

```
#import "TouchDelegate.h"

@interface MyView : UIView
@property (weak, nonatomic) id<TouchDelegate> touchDelegate;
...
@end
```

and then delegate as normal:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if ([_touchDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(touchesBegan:withEvent:)]) {
        [_touchDelegate touchesBegain:touches withEvent:event];
    }
}

// etc.
```

Comment: @LordZsolt No, it won't.  And yes, great minds... :)

Comment: Thanks your answer is also true but i cannot accept 2 answers as true. UpVoted at least.

Comment: @yucelbayram Yep, no problem.